# socketio_manage - NameSpace

Tags: socket.io, gevent, gevent-socketio

Can anyone explain in detail about the gevent socketio_manage, What is namespace and how methods inside Namesspaces are called?

I verified many documents online, but not got any clear description about socketio_manage